# Is this the correct way to think about the client/server socket relationship?

Tags: java, networking, distributed-computing, distributed-development

I'm designing a distributed application, very basic for now. The idea is that once the application is active on all machines (about 5 vms), you can initiate a `grep` on all log files from all machines from any one machine.

Generally, the steps would be:

- Launch the application on all machines
- All applications pause in a wait condition of `Press [Enter] to continue...`
- Once `[Enter]` is pressed, that particular machine is the issuer of commands, so to speak
- You type your desired pattern, and it issues the commands to all machines, pulling down the results

At first, my plan was to do connection setup after the user pressed `[Enter]`, setting up a `client` connection for the host issuing the commands, and `server` connections on the rest; but this seems not very scalable. My idea now is to just initiate all connections from the start, both a `client` and `server`, and just always be polling the `server` socket for incoming queries.

Is this standard practice, or should I be looking at a different way to monitor / setup connections? Are there any basic design principles or best practices for building distributed connections?

Comment: For what it's worth, there's already several tools to run commands on multiple servers via SSH: check out this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19010/57959

Comment: Thanks, the intent here though is to get familiar with distributed development. So this is more-or-less an introductory application for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Having a number of client connections to numerous remote nodes is not that intensive so that should not be a problem in that respect. For the data rate that you can expect from a terminal, you might consider non-blocking I/O with callbacks and a single server with a thread per client or a thread pool to process the response messages. This should scale until you are processing bound with your connections.

You could then set up your connections either in advance or as needed. Working on an as needed basis will avoid a startup hit if there are no tight time requirements for getting the list of files at about the same time. If you want more details, provide a diagram and we can discuss.